# Java string to URI with parameters

Tags: java, http, url, uri

I have this query string to send a http request via a **URI object**, but the URI object **reformats my query string**, including the parameters.

Comment: You are using the constructor wrong. Your path should go in the `path` variable and your query string should go in the `queryString` variable. The `URI` is escaping the query because you are telling it that it's part of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the "query" part to the path.  You want

```
queryString /* misnamed */ += "/v2/cart/addProduct";
String query = "?...";
...
uri = new URI("http", null, getDomain(), 80, queryString, query, null);
```